# How to count the number of Form selects that have had values changes in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have several selects in my form. If one select has had its options changed then it should increase the counter. 5 selects then counter should be 5. Essentially I want to check if all my selects have been selected so I can submit the form. I don't want to use "required".

```
<div id="firstPanelID"
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <label class="fixingLabelAlignmentInner">Transfer Code of Center from which Infant Transferred : </label>
        <div class="fixingInputAlignmentInner">
            <select id="transferCodePIW" name=transferCodePIW class="form-control" style="height:32px;width:80%;">
            <option disabled selected value>SELECT</option>
            <option value="13240">13240 - Mowbray Maternity Hospital</option>
            <option value="14994">14994 - New Somerset Hospital</option>
            <option value="16011">16011 - Tygerberg Hospital</option>
            <option value="8005432">8005432 - Khayelitsha District Hospital</option>
            <option value="8005433">8005433 - Michell's Plain District Hospital</option>
            <option value="8005435">8005435 - Red Cross Children's Hospital</option>
            <option value="97777777">97777777 - Birth at Home or in Transit</option>
            <option value="">Other</option>
            <option value="77777777">N/A</option>
            <option value="99999999">Unknown</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried it with the following. The selects may be visible/invisible due to other radio buttons hence the visible. The function works for radio buttons but I can't get it to work for selects.

```
var sgroups = [];
    $('#firstPanelID select:visible:selected').each(function(index, el){
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < sgroups.length; i++)
                if(sgroups[i] == $(el).attr('name'))
                    return true;
            sgroups.push($(el).attr('name'));
        }
    );
alert(($('#firstPanelID select:visible:selected').length))
```

Comment: Each select should increase counter only 1? Or for each selection?

Comment: Each select should only increase by max 1. I am comparing it by counting the number of selects on the screen. If there are 5, then the counter should be 5.

Comment: `count = $("#transferCodePIW :selected").length;`

Comment: The above still isn't counting if its selected or not.

Comment: That gives it a value of 1 when I haven't even changed the select.

Answer (score 3):

I think the code is self-explanatory.

```js
var counter = 0;

$('select').change(function () {
  var o = $(this);
 if (!o.hasClass('counted')) {
   counter++;
    o.addClass('counted');
   }
    
  $('#counter').text(counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="aa">aa</option>
<option value="bb">bb</option>
<option value="cc">cc</option>
</select>
<select>
<option value="2aa">2aa</option>
<option value="2bb">2bb</option>
<option value="2cc">2cc</option>
</select>
<select>
<option value="3aa">3aa</option>
<option value="3bb">3bb</option>
<option value="3cc">3cc</option>
</select>

<div id="counter">
0
</div>
```

Comment: What if the option was selected, and then unselected, this would give it the class `counted` even though it's not selected

Comment: OP didn't specify this. First, save the value of the select, later check if the select changes back to the saved value. If yes, remove class.

Comment: add an `else` statement

Comment: I explained the idea. You're free to implement it as you like.

Comment: And you can also try `counter = $("#transferCodePIW :selected").length;` inside the `change` listener

Comment: options won't be unselected. 

This works but it doesn't account for only visible selects. How do I deal with that?

Comment: @LarryLiu what do you mean exactly? Explain again

Comment: This code here works for radio buttons :     `$('#firstPanelID input:radio:visible:checked').length`

But I just need it to work with selects. I don't really want to change the whole function

Comment: You can leave your old code. Just add the code above to your JS.

Comment: This is not how SO works. You asked something. With the code you provided, I gave a working answer. From this point on, this discussion about your original question is useless. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if all selects have been checked, assuming each select will have an empty value, you can do this:

```
function isThereAnyEmptySelection () {
    let r = false;
    $('select').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') { // or === null, or === undefined, or === '0' etc., depending on context
            r = true;
        }
    });
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.one()` to attach a single `change` event to each `<select>` element, when `count` is equal to `$("selector").length` call `.off()` to remove `change` event, then perform action, for example, submit `<form>` element.

```js
let count = 0;

$("select").one("change", function() {

  ++count;
  
  console.log(count);
  if (count === $("select").length) {
    $("select").off("change");
    // submit form here
    console.log(count + " is " + $("select").length)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```